# Django Rest framework Field is Required error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Email(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    sender = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    receiver = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = models.TextField()
```

My serializer.py:

```
from django.forms import widgets
from rest_framework import serializers
from email_app.models import Email

class EmailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Email
        fields = ('id', 'sender', 'receiver', 'message')
```

My views.py:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def email_list(request):
    serializer = EmailSerializer(data=request.DATA)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

When I send a POST request like this:

```
 curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/email/new/ -d "{'sender': 'a@b', 'receiver':'c@d', 'message':''yolo'}"
```

I get this error:

```
{"message": ["This field is required."], "sender": ["This field is required."], "receiver": ["This field is required."]}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DRF needs the `Content-Type` header to find the correct parser for your data.

Try to add `-H "Content-Type:application/json"` to your curl-call.

Also note single-quotes (`'`)as you use them aren't valid JSON. JSON only allows double-quotes (`"`).

So your correct curl-call would be

`curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/email/new/ -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"sender": "a@b", "receiver":"c@d", "message":"yolo"}'`