# django-rest-framework "This field is required" on POST

Tags: django, curl, django-rest-framework, django-contenttypes

Whenever I POST to my django-rest-framework (DRF) endpoints, I keep receiving a `"HTTP 400 Bad Request"  {"offeror_organization":["This field is required."]}` response. But, given the curl example below, I'm clearly specifying a value.

This happens regardless of the Content-Type (application/json, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data). The only time it works is when I submit using the "HTML form" (vs. the "Raw Data") tab on the DRF web interface.

There's a few similar SO posts (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074089/django-rest-framework-field-is-required-error/24076123) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30802785/django-rest-framework-this-field-is-required-only-when-posting-json-not-when)), but none of the solutions seem to be working for me.

**Model:**

```
class OrganizationManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, offeror_organization):
        return self.get(offeror_organization=offeror_organization)

class Organization(models.Model):
    idorganization = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    offeror_organization = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='Offeror Organization')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=False)

    objects = OrganizationManager()

    def natural_key(self):
        return "%s" % (self.offeror_organization)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.offeror_organization
```

**Serializer:**

```
class OrganizationSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = ['offeror_organization']

    # I've tried both with and without a create function
    def create(self, validated_data): 
        organization_data = validated_data.pop('offeror_organization', None)
        if organization_data:
            organization = Organization.objects.get_or_create(**organization_data)[0]
            validated_data['offeror_organization'] = organization
```

**views/api.py:**

```
from webapp.models import Organization
from webapp.serializers import OrganizationSerializer

from rest_framework import viewsets

class OrganizationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Organization.objects.all().order_by('offeror_organization')
    serializer_class = OrganizationSerializer
```

****urls.py:****

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'organization', views.OrganizationViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
]
```

**Curl Command:**

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"offeror_organization":"Test2"}' 10.101.10.228:29000/webapp/api/organization/
```

**settings.py MIDDLEWARE:**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'csp.middleware.CSPMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware'
]
```

**settings.py REST_FRAMEWORK**

```
# currently have all API authentication disabled while troubleshooting this issue
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [],
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the view of this endpoint?

Comment: @arthursribeiro I've posted the view code (forgot that I had it) as well as my urls.py.

Comment: Can you share your middlewares? And your REST_FRAMEWORK var in settings.py

Comment: @Michael updated post above.

Comment: @littleK I would remove the non-default middlewares temporarily and see if they have to do with this.

Comment: @Michael good idea, but that unfortunately doesn't seem to be the case. I just tried systematically disabling a bunch of middlewares and unfortunately same result. This issue is driving me nuts.

Comment: The order is important. Did you try with the exact same list that comes by default?

Comment: @Michael Yep, same list found here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/middleware/

Comment: Weird.. Are you sending the request directly to django? or is there any other proxy in between?

Comment: In my Test environment, I have a nginx proxy in-between with uwsgi as the django application server (using socket, not http). Perhaps that's the issue. In my local dev environment (no proxy and no uwsgi), I see the same behaviour in DRF's RESTful web interface BUT it looks like POST requests with cURL and Postman are working there...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231237/discussion-between-littlek-and-michael).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, fixing this issue required "maneuvering" around a few different implementation constraints.

**nginx + uWSGI Socket + Django REMOTE_USER Authentication**:
As mentioned in this post's comments/chat, I've got both an nginx proxy and a uWSGI application server fronting my Django application. Since I'm relying upon [REMOTE_USER Authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/auth-remote-user/), my uwsgi/nginx configuration **must** use uWSGI sockets (vs. http) so that I may pass the REMOTE_USER from nginx to Django as an environment variable. When using http (coupled w/ nginx proxy_pass), although proxy_pass can set headers or cookies, those seemingly cannot translate over to Django (which requires the environment variable).

I think there's a few issues at play when trying to POST to a Django/DRF application served using uWSGI sockets. Per the uWSGI [Things to know (best practices)](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ThingsToKnow.html), *"TL/DR: if you plan to expose uWSGI directly to the public, use --http, if you want to proxy it behind a webserver speaking http with backends, use --http-socket".* In my case, having both a web application and a DRF-based API (that I want other services and systems to talk to), I need both! As a (hopefully temporary) workaround, I'm currently spawning **two** uWSGI processes - one using `--socket`, and one using `--http` (for API POST calls). If you POST while using ---socket, you'll likely get an Empty Response error from DRF.

As an aside, I initially saw some "promise" in utilizing uwsgi_curl (from [uwsgi_tools](https://github.com/andreif/uwsgi-tools)) to POST over the uWSGI socket (which resulted in the "*field is required*" error (vs. the Empty Response error), but that's when I started to run into my second issue...

**POST nested application/json w/ simultaneous file upload:** The "Organization" model referenced in the post was mostly proof-of-concept, as it's the least complex model in my Django application. In reality, I need to post to a more complex model with nested serialization, as the model contains Foreign Key's to other models. But that's totally do-able with DRF. *Except* in my case, where one of my model attributes is a FileUpload field. As noted in other SO Questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439961/python-requests-post-json-and-file-in-single-request/35946962) one), there's also a few issues in trying to POST *nested (i.e. not "flat")* application/json with a file upload in a single request. While I was never able to fully understand the issue at play (at least using `drf_writable_nested.serializers.WritableNestedModelSerializer` in my case), I simplified the problem at-hand by writing my own custom Serializer (serializers.Serializer), this way I could avoid nested JSON objects (like { "offeror_organization": {"offeror_organization: "Test"}} in my POST requests. This fixed my issue.

With the custom serializer in place to mitigate the nested JSON + file upload issue, I bet the uwsgi_curl POST would work. Although then external client systems/services are limited to using that Python package. Anyways, I'll update my answer once I try it out. Thanks to @Michael for his comments and helping to lead me down the right "road".

Answer (score 0):

I have the same setup (nginx + gunicorn + django + rest-framework + drf-writeable-nested) but I could figure out a valid format for the POST request containing `multipart/form-data`:

It needs to be like this:

json:

```
{
   'name': 'test-name',
   'files': [
      {
         'file': 'test-file-1'
      },
      {
         'file': 'test-file-2'
      },
      ...
   ],
   ...
}
```

must be formatted to:

FormData:

```
name: test-name
files[0]file: test-file-1
files[1]file: test-file-2
...
```

Some libraries would use a dot after the brackets for nested lists, which would lead to the `This field is required` error. Or even another bracket after the list bracket would lead to the same error.
This is wrong:
`files[0].file`
This is also wrong:
`files[0][file]`

My example assumes the following Django-classes:

```
# views.py

from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser
from .serializers import YourCustomModelSerializer

class YourCustomModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = YourCustomModel.objects.all()
    parser_classes = [FormParser, MultiPartParser]
    permission_classes = []
    serializer_class = YourCustomModelSerializer
```

```
# serializers.py

from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from drf_writable_nested.serializers import WritableNestedModelSerializer
from .models import YourCustomModel, File

class FileSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = ['file']

class YourCustomModelSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    # Reverse foreign key
    files = FileSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = YourCustomModel
        read_only_fields = ('id', )
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'files'
        ]
```

```
# models.py

from django.db import models

class File(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField()

class YourCustomModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I used the following javascript/typescript frontend code to pack my json data into a FormData request:

```js
const requestBody = {
  name: 'test-name',
  files: [
    { file: file1 }, // File object
    { file: file2 }, // File object
    { file: file3 }  // File object
  ]
}

// # use your own code to serialize the above javascript dict/json/object
// into form-data object (I used the library https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-to-formdata but I had to write a patch for the exact reason described above: files[0].file is not correctly parsed by Django and files[0][file] also won't work, therefore I slightly changed the library code so that it will format my object to files[0]file for every nested item:

// 2. prepare a serializer-library to convert the dict into a special form which can be parsed by django.
const options = {
  indices: true,
  allowEmptyArrays: true,
  useDotOrBracketsOrNothingForNestedObjects: 2 // Option 0: DOT-Notation, 1: Brackets, 2: Nothing (this option is from my custom patch)
}

// use npx patch: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62567504/3433137
// (I patched this serialize library and the patch is somewhere stored as a file in this project)
const formData = serialize(
  requestBody,
  options
)
    
// 3. upload the data
api.post(url, formData)
```